# Change font size and font family in Rich text editor

Tags: reactjs, react-native, draftjs

How to change font size and font family while using react-native draftjs editor ?

I am using it from below given NPM link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draftjs-editor

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is delayed. Basically, what you do is create a styleMap, then add the map to your editor via the customStyleMap property.

```
const styleMap = {
    'LARGETEXT' : {
        color: 'blue',
        fontSize: '12rem'
    }
}

<Editor customStyleMap={styleMap} />
```

Finally, just make the change when you press a button that will change the text using the Draft.js Modifier object:

```
// your function:

const styledContentState = Modifier.applyInlineStyle(
            editorState.getCurrentContent(),
            editorState.getSelection(),
            'LARGETEXT'
   );
   const newState = EditorState.set(editorState, {
            currentContent: styledContentState
   });
```

Note that you can create a toggle function as well that checks if the style is on the selection and then just use the removeInlineStyle function.